# Opera Mini Compression Technology

Tags: website, compression, opera

I'm trying to find the technology used in Opera Mini's browser. I can't find anything related to this, so I would like to know if anyone knows whether there exists a paper on this or if there is something else available to the public. I would like to create my own compression server based on the technology.

Comment: AFAIK that is proprietary technology and not a published algorithm although the concept is fairly trivial : use a proxy server to resize images and compress other content but because client and server are from the same vendor they don’t need to be standards based and can use custom and proprietary methods and shortcuts to achieve compression ratios even over https that other solutions can’t. But probably OT for ServerFault...

Comment: Maybe not completely proprietary https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini

Comment: @HermanB I know that I can compress images but I would like how the other methods are achieved. E.g.: How does Opera Mini remove unnecessary CSS? I tried recreating it but it took hell long.